# Is the openjdk-r ppa trustworthy enough to install on server?

Tags: ubuntu, java

We are running ubuntu 14.04, which still does not have openjdk8 yet. And I doubt they are going to fix this very soon. We need jdk8 very badly. Is this openjdk-r ppa safe enough?

Comment: Define "safe enough"

Comment: This has been answered already on http://askubuntu.com/questions/705072/is-the-openjdk-r-ppa-trustworty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Installing `openjdk-8` from this Launchpad PPA is safe.
To install OpenJDK 8 execute the following commands :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openjdk-r/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk
```

Comment: I think we should be able to trust Matthias Klose.